# Change color of pie chart with google sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using Python google sheet API v4 to produce a pie chart using the following code:

```
body = {
      "requests": [
        {
          "addChart": {
            "chart": {
              "spec": {
                  "backgroundColorStyle" : {
                      "themeColor": "BACKGROUND"
                    },
                "pieChart": {
                  "legendPosition": "LABELED_LEGEND",
                    "pieHole":0.7,
                  "domain": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 0,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": last_row,
                          "startColumnIndex": 0,
                          "endColumnIndex": 1
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 0,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 7,
                          "startColumnIndex": 3,
                          "endColumnIndex": 4
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                }
              },
              "position": {
                "overlayPosition": {
                  "anchorCell": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "rowIndex": 1,
                    "columnIndex": 5
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=sheet_id, body=body)
response = request.execute()
```

This get me exactly what I want, but I would like to set the color of each slice according to a give color palette. I've looked for a way to do so but haven't found it, so is it possible to do so thought the API?

To further clarify with an image, this is what I get with 4 class. How can I set the color of this 4 slice to go from green, blu, yellow, red to green, purple, yellow, orange?
[Graph I get with 4 class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sFKY.png)

Comment: In order to correctly understand your goal, can I ask you about the detail of `I would like to set the color of each slice according to a give color palette`?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, thank you for your reply! Ideally I would be able to set a parameter that automatically define all the color slices. But it would be more than enough to be able to manually set the color for each one. For example now when I generate I piechart with 4 classes I get the following color: green, blu, yellow, red. How can I set for example: green, purple, yellow, orange?

Comment: I also added an image, hope this clarify my question

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood your question. Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that the colors cannot be changed using Sheets API. I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug. So, I would like to recommend reporting this to the Google issue tracker. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)